# Generate a Dynamic Form based on Primefaces-extensions DynaForm from Database at Runtime and allow the Form's Data storage

Tags: jpa, dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I would like to create a dynamic form where I generate a form from the database at runtime, but also create data storage table on the database server using fields provided at runtime (using JPA). I have tried all in my capacity and at this time, I need help. I will be as descriptive as possible to show where my problem is, and what exactly I want to achieve.

When I searched here on StackOverflow, I found out that to do a dynamic form in primefaces, I have to use the Primefaces-Extensions DynaForm. I borrowed a leaf from the examples in the primefaces-extensions showcase and I managed to implement it rightly as below.

[image]

**The DynaFormController**

```
@PostConstruct  
protected void initialize() {  
    model = new DynaFormModel();  

    // add rows, labels and editable controls  
    // set relationship between label and editable controls to support outputLabel with "for" attribute  

    // 1. row  
    DynaFormRow row = model.createRegularRow();  

    DynaFormLabel label11 = row.addLabel("Author");  
    DynaFormControl control12 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("OurAuthor", true), "input");  
    label11.setForControl(control12); 


    DynaFormLabel label13 = row.addLabel("ISBN");  
    DynaFormControl control14 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("ISBN", true), "input");  
    label13.setForControl(control14);  

    // 2. row  
    row = model.createRegularRow();  

    DynaFormLabel label21 = row.addLabel("Title");  
    DynaFormControl control22 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Title", false), "input", 3, 1);  
    label21.setForControl(control22);  

    // 3. row  
    row = model.createRegularRow();  

    DynaFormLabel label31 = row.addLabel("Publisher");  
    DynaFormControl control32 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Publisher", false), "input");  
    label31.setForControl(control32);  

    DynaFormLabel label33 = row.addLabel("Published on");  
    DynaFormControl control34 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Published on", false), "calendar");  
    label33.setForControl(control34);  

    // 4. row  
    row = model.createRegularRow();  

    DynaFormLabel label41 = row.addLabel("Language");  
    DynaFormControl control42 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Language", false), "select");  
    label41.setForControl(control42);  

    DynaFormLabel label43 = row.addLabel("Description", 1, 2);  
    DynaFormControl control44 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Description", false), "textarea", 1, 2);  
    label43.setForControl(control44);  

    // 5. row  
    row = model.createRegularRow();  

    DynaFormLabel label51 = row.addLabel("Rating");  
    DynaFormControl control52 = row.addControl(new BookProperty("Rating", 3, true), "rating");  
    label51.setForControl(control52);  
}  

public DynaFormModel getModel() {  
    return model;  
}  

public List<BookProperty> getBookProperties() {  
    if (model == null) {  
        return null;  
    }  

    List<BookProperty> bookProperties = new ArrayList<BookProperty>();  
    for (DynaFormControl dynaFormControl : model.getControls()) {  
        bookProperties.add((BookProperty) dynaFormControl.getData());  
    }  

    return bookProperties;  
}  

public String submitForm() {  
    FacesMessage.Severity sev = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity();  
    boolean hasErrors = (sev != null && (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.compareTo(sev) >= 0));  

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    requestContext.addCallbackParam("isValid", !hasErrors);  

    return null;  
}
```

**The DynaForm .xhtml definition**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
        <h:panelGroup id="dynaFormGroup">  
            <p:messages id="messages" showSummary="true"/>  

            <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{dynaFormController.model}" var="data">  
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="input" for="txt">  
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}" />  
                </pe:dynaFormControl>  
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="calendar" for="cal" styleClass="calendar">  
                    <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}" showOn="button"/>  
                </pe:dynaFormControl>  
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="select" for="sel" styleClass="select">  
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="sel" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}">  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dynaFormController.languages}"/>  
                    </p:selectOneMenu>  
                </pe:dynaFormControl>  
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="textarea" for="tarea">  
                    <p:inputTextarea id="tarea" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}" autoResize="false"/>  
                </pe:dynaFormControl>  
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="rating" for="rat">  
                    <p:rating id="rat" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}"/>  
                </pe:dynaFormControl>  

                <f:facet name="buttonBar">  
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dynaFormController.submitForm}"  
                                     process="dynaForm" update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup :mainForm:inputValues"  
                                     oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"/>  
                    <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" style="margin-left: 5px;"/>  
                </f:facet>  
            </pe:dynaForm>  
        </h:panelGroup>  

        <p:dialog header="Input values" widgetVar="inputValuesWidget">  
            <p:dataList id="inputValues" value="#{dynaFormController.bookProperties}" var="bookProperty"  
                        style="margin:10px;">  
                <h:outputText value="#{bookProperty.name}: #{bookProperty.formattedValue}"  
                              style="margin-right: 10px;"/>  
            </p:dataList>  
        </p:dialog>  

        <h:outputScript id="dynaFormScript" target="body">  
            /* <![CDATA[ */ 
            function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) { 
            if(args && args.isValid) { 
            PF('inputValuesWidget').show(); 
            } else { 
            PF('inputValuesWidget').hide(); 
            } 
            } 
            /* ]]> */  
        </h:outputScript>  

        <h:outputStylesheet id="dynaFormCSS">  
            /* note: trick with colspan is needed for IE8 */  
            .pe-dynaform-cell input,  
            .pe-dynaform-cell textarea,  
            .pe-dynaform-cell[colspan="1"] input,  
            .pe-dynaform-cell[colspan="1"] textarea {  
            width: 150px;  
            }  

            /* note: trick with colspan is needed for IE8 */  
            .pe-dynaform-cell.calendar input,  
            .pe-dynaform-cell[colspan="1"].calendar input {  
            width: 120px;  
            }  

            .pe-dynaform-cell.select .ui-selectonemenu {  
            width: 157px !important;  
            }  

            .pe-dynaform-cell.select .ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {  
            width: 130px !important;  
            }  
        </h:outputStylesheet>    
    </h:form>
```

**I am transforming from this:**. When you look at the DynaFormController, it is where all the DynaForm definition is done. Forexample, If I want to add a new field on my Form, I don't have to change the .xhtml, but I have to go to the DynaFormController and define it.

What I want and what I have tried to do is to store my form definition in the database, so that instead of defining a new field in the DynaFormCOntroller, I will add the field and its definition in the database at runtime and the DynaFormController will pick it automatically. In otherwords, the DynaFormController builds the DynaForm from the database at runtime.

**I have a database table to store the DynaForm Fields and their definition**

[image]

**I capture my DynaForm Definition from here**

I can create any number of fields and their definition and they will be stored in the database table. As shown below.

[image]

Note: The rowNumber field I added is for layout purposes. If u see the generated form below, u realize firstName and secondName are in the same row. If u compare it with the form definition above, u can see that both firstName and secondName are on rowNumber 4.

After all the DynaForm definition is stored in the database, I generate the form below from the database.

**The DynaForm generated from the database**

[image]

When I click submit on the above form, I have a table in the database that stores the data.

[image]

**Here is the DynaFormController that generates the DynaForm From the database.**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DynaFormBacking implements Serializable{    

private @Inject
DynaFormAttributeFacade dynaFormAttributeFacade;
private List<DynaFormAttribute> dynaFormAttributeList;

private DynaFormModel model;

private @Inject TblPersonFacade personFacade;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of DynaFormBacking
 */

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    model = new DynaFormModel();
    DynaFormRow row;
    DynaFormLabel label;
    DynaFormControl control;

    int i = 0; //loop incrementer
    //Number of form attributes.
    int listSize = getDynaFormAttributeList().size(); 
    for (; i < listSize;) {
        //Get form attributes that belong to the same row 
        List<DynaFormAttribute> rowDynaFormList = dynaFormAttributeFacade.getEntityRowsGivenColumnValue(new DynaFormAttribute(), "rowNumber", getDynaFormAttributeList().get(i).getRowNumber());
        //create a new row
        row = model.createRegularRow();
        //place labels and controls on the newly created row. If we have multiple fields on the same row, this loop will place them
        for (int r = 0; r < rowDynaFormList.size(); r++) {
            //place label and control on the row (This is for a single form attribute)
            label = row.addLabel(rowDynaFormList.get(r).getLabelName(), rowDynaFormList.get(r).getLabelColspan(), rowDynaFormList.get(r).getLabelRowspan());
            control = row.addControl(new Person(false), rowDynaFormList.get(r).getControlName(), rowDynaFormList.get(r).getControlColspan(), rowDynaFormList.get(r).getControlRowspan());
            label.setForControl(control);
            //increment to keep track of the number of form attributes
            i++;
        }
    }

}
public DynaFormBacking() {
}

public DynaFormModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

//This list picks the form fields and their definitions from the database
public List<DynaFormAttribute> getDynaFormAttributeList() {
    dynaFormAttributeList = dynaFormAttributeFacade.findAll();
    return dynaFormAttributeList;
}

public String submitForm() {  
    FacesMessage.Severity sev = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity();  
    boolean hasErrors = (sev != null && (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.compareTo(sev) >= 0));  

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    requestContext.addCallbackParam("isValid", !hasErrors);  

        TblPerson person = new TblPerson();
        person.setFirstName((String) getPersonList().get(0).getFormattedValue());
        person.setSecondName((String) getPersonList().get(1).getFormattedValue());
        person.setSex((String) getPersonList().get(2).getFormattedValue());
        person.setDateOfBirth( (Date) getPersonList().get(3).getFormattedValue());
        person.setPhone((String) getPersonList().get(4).getFormattedValue());

        personFacade.create(person);
    return null;  

}


public List<Person> getPersonList() {  
    if (model == null) {  
        return null;  
    }  

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();  
    for (DynaFormControl dynaFormControl : model.getControls()) {  
        personList.add((Person) dynaFormControl.getData());  
    }  

    return personList;  
}

}
```

Here is my Implementation of the getENtityRowsGivenColumnValue method which I used in the above Controller

```
    /**
 * This method returns Entity rows of data specific to the given column
 * value - return rows when given a column name and the column value
 */
public List<T> getEntityRowsGivenColumnValue(T entity, String columnName, Object columnValue) {
    List<T> resultList;
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(rt).where(cb.equal(rt.get(columnName), columnValue));
    javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    try {
        resultList = q.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        resultList = null;
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Here is the Person Class I used in the above Controller

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped //Must be request scoped. otherwise, it won't work
public class Person implements  Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 20120521L; 

private Object value;
private boolean required;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of Person
 */
public Person() {
}

public Person(boolean required) {
    this.required = required;
}

public Person(Object value, boolean required) {
    this.value = value;
    this.required = required;
}


public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public boolean isRequired() {
    return required;
}

public void setRequired(boolean required) {
    this.required = required;
}

public Object getFormattedValue() {  
    if (value instanceof Date) {  
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  

        return simpleDateFormat.format(value);  
    }  

    return value;  
}

}
```

Here is the TblPerson Entity Class I used in the above controller

```
public class TblPerson implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "secondName")
private String secondName;
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "sex")
private String sex;
@Column(name = "dateOfBirth")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;
// @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

public TblPerson() {
}

public TblPerson(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}

public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof TblPerson)) {
        return false;
    }
    TblPerson other = (TblPerson) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ijmis.model.TblPerson[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

Here is the DynaFormAttribute Entity Class I used in the Controller

```
public class DynaFormAttribute implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "labelName")
private String labelName;
@Column(name = "labelColspan")
private Integer labelColspan;
@Column(name = "labelRowspan")
private Integer labelRowspan;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "controlName")
private String controlName;
@Column(name = "controlColspan")
private Integer controlColspan;
@Column(name = "controlRowspan")
private Integer controlRowspan;
@Column(name = "rowNumber")
private Integer rowNumber;

public DynaFormAttribute() {
}

public DynaFormAttribute(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLabelName() {
    return labelName;
}

public void setLabelName(String labelName) {
    this.labelName = labelName;
}

public Integer getLabelColspan() {
    return labelColspan;
}

public void setLabelColspan(Integer labelColspan) {
    this.labelColspan = labelColspan;
}

public Integer getLabelRowspan() {
    return labelRowspan;
}

public void setLabelRowspan(Integer labelRowspan) {
    this.labelRowspan = labelRowspan;
}

public String getControlName() {
    return controlName;
}

public void setControlName(String controlName) {
    this.controlName = controlName;
}

public Integer getControlColspan() {
    return controlColspan;
}

public void setControlColspan(Integer controlColspan) {
    this.controlColspan = controlColspan;
}

public Integer getControlRowspan() {
    return controlRowspan;
}

public void setControlRowspan(Integer controlRowspan) {
    this.controlRowspan = controlRowspan;
}

public Integer getRowNumber() {
    return rowNumber;
}

public void setRowNumber(Integer rowNumber) {
    this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof DynaFormAttribute)) {
        return false;
    }
    DynaFormAttribute other = (DynaFormAttribute) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ijmis.model.DynaFormAttribute[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

**This is where I need Help**:After reading all this, u might be asking ur self what exactly am trying to ask. This is where I really need help:

**1. Data Storage:** I generate all the form fields at runtime, but my data storage table is statically created. In otherwards, even if am creating my form fields at runtime, It is logical to create only fields that I have in my data storage table. **How can I create my data storage table dynamically at runtime without putting data integrity and constraints at risk, so that I will have database table with fields I have defined at runtime?** I actually want that the first time i will deploy the application forexample, I will create a form definition and store it in the database, generate a dynamic form from the database, but also create a database table to store the data of the fields at runtime. This should be done once the first time the application is setup. (Part of this question could be boiling down to, how can I create an entity at runtime and run it on the db server to create an actual table at runtime?)

2.This implementation only allows me to capture new data from the user and store it as it is given. What can I do if I want to perfom some logic on the field value before I submit it in the database? Also, sometimes, there are cases where there might be need to provide some values of the form automatically when the form loads. e.g you might want to generate an employee number and show it as a readonly field when a new record is being capture. With my implementation, how would I achieve that?

***This is a really long question, but Prior thanks for your kind and well thought contribution. I promise that your contribution will be of great help.***

Comment: I have a simular problem and need to create 'responsive' forms. So not the DynaForm that generates <table> but to generate <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the data in a large text field in XML format. You would need code to convert the XML into your entities and back. This would be database agnostic and it would work well with your field definition scheme. Indexing and relationships would be difficult to implement though.

If you don't mind getting database specific you could write stored procedures and trigger functions to create the dynamic tables when records are created in the data definition tables. I developed such a system about ten years ago for documentation of equipment to allow for dynamic equipment types.